# Ajax request called once on mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows-phone-8

Code works fine on pc. But on windows phone(and posibly other mobiles)  ajax request triggered only once time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pl'>
    <head>
        <title>Oświetlenie - Esp8266</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>


        <link href='https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src='https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-5'>
                <input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' id='bulbswitch' name='bulb' >
            </div>
        </div>



        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#bulbswitch').on('change',function(){ 
                $.ajax({ url: '/trigger',type: 'GET'});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What i'm doing wrong, mobiel phones need special request type?

Add `cache:false` on ajax call solved issue :)

Comment: add your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cache:false` on ajax call solved issue :)

Comment: Hello user3468055 ! You can accept your own answers in order to close the question.